# After configuring Elixir Phoenix to use Tailwind standalone, how do I enable tailwindcss/nesting?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, tailwind-css

I successfully followed [Chris McCord's Tailwind Standalone for Phoenix instructions](https://fly.io/phoenix-files/tailwind-standalone/) to add Tailwind.

But I want to enable the `tailwindcss/nesting` plugin. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors says:

> It’s included directly in the tailwindcss package itself, so to use it
> all you need to do is add it to your PostCSS configuration, somewhere
> before Tailwind…

But when I add the two `require` specifiers to my `tailwind.config.js` like this:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './js/**/*.js',
    '../lib/*_web/**/*.*ex'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('tailwindcss/nesting'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
  ],
}
```

...I get (when I run `mix phx.server`):

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933
  const err = new Error(message);
              ^

Error: Cannot find module 'tailwindcss/nesting'
Require stack:
- /Users/dspitzer/dev/from_github/ssauction_live_fly/assets/tailwind.config.js
- /snapshot/tailwindcss/lib/cli.js
- /snapshot/tailwindcss/standalone-cli/standalone.js
1) If you want to compile the package/file into executable, please pay attention to compilation warnings and specify a literal in 'require' call. 2) If you don't want to compile the package/file into executable and want to 'require' it from filesystem (likely plugin), specify an absolute path in 'require' call using process.cwd() or process.execPath.
```

So much for it being included in the tailwindcss package itself.

I noticed when I remote the `tailwindcss/nesting` plugin require from my `tailwind.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './js/**/*.js',
    '../lib/*_web/**/*.*ex'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('tailwindcss'),
  ],
}
```

...I still get:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933
  const err = new Error(message);
              ^

Error: Cannot find module 'tailwindcss'
Require stack:
- /Users/dspitzer/dev/from_github/ssauction_live_fly/assets/tailwind.config.js
- /snapshot/tailwindcss/lib/cli.js
- /snapshot/tailwindcss/standalone-cli/standalone.js
1) If you want to compile the package/file into executable, please pay attention to compilation warnings and specify a literal in 'require' call. 2) If you don't want to compile the package/file into executable and want to 'require' it from filesystem (likely plugin), specify an absolute path in 'require' call using process.cwd() or process.execPath.
```

In case this helps:

```
$ which tailwindcss
/Users/dspitzer/bin/tailwindcss
$ tailwindcss --help

tailwindcss v3.0.7

Usage:
   tailwindcss [--input input.css] [--output output.css] [--watch] [options...]
   tailwindcss init [--full] [--postcss] [options...]

Commands:
   init [options]

Options:
   -i, --input              Input file
   -o, --output             Output file
   -w, --watch              Watch for changes and rebuild as needed
       --content            Content paths to use for removing unused classes
       --postcss            Load custom PostCSS configuration
   -m, --minify             Minify the output
   -c, --config             Path to a custom config file
       --no-autoprefixer    Disable autoprefixer
   -h, --help               Display usage information
```

(I'm using macOS.)

Answer (score 0):

These are related issues with some hints in the github tailwind repository:

[Does Tailwind CLI support the nested classes?](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/7216)

[Tailwind Cli doesn't support nested classes](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/7691)